# after have a Android HTTP Get....Wrong in String

Tags: android

I Get a long String from an  Android HTTP get. The String has many Chinese words in it, so I get lots of scrambled code In my String. That makes my parser unworkable. I've heard about the data from server is kind of raw data. How can I translate the scrambled code to readable code (in Chinese)?

I've tried  this following, but it doesn't work.

```
 String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
 byte[] queryBytes = retSrc.getBytes("Raw Data");
 String Str = new String(queryBytes,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: You need to use the right encoding.

Comment: But how should I do for the right result....

I'm a newb in Android....sorry about my stupid....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] queryBytes = retSrc.getBytes("Raw Data");
```

**Raw Data** is a charset encoder?

the encoding is an ugly problem, some suggestion:

when the string get from the site, try 'utf-8' or 'gbk' to encoding.
if the string printed to the console is right, maybe the encoding is right.

Comment: I've tried in 
    `byte[] queryBytes = retSrc.getBytes("gbk");`
    `String Str = new String(queryBytes,"utf-8");`
and
     `byte[] queryBytes = retSrc.getBytes("gbk");`
     `String Str = new String(queryBytes,"utf-8");` 

the return string in Chinese still remain scrambled
but....it is different scramble code.....But still scrambled...冏

Comment: 你在最初讀取的時候，加上編碼，得到string以後，不用再轉碼

Comment: 是這樣的，就是你從網路上最開始的時候是流，你在從 流->string 時候這個時候加入編碼，那就直接就是編碼好的 string 了

Comment: `String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());`
網路上說這邊就已經算用utf-8編碼了＠＠。。是我看錯了嗎。。求大大指導

Comment: 如果默認是 UTF-8，那你得到string以後如果是正確的，那編碼就是對的，如果還是有問題的話，你改成 String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()，"gbk") 試試

Comment: String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(),"utf-8");
解決了！！！謝謝大大們

愛死你們了!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the correct encoding of the page content, eg. Big5, GB2312 or UTF-8, then try the following function to get the page content:

```
public String getURLContent(String URL, String encoding) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                response.getEntity().getContent(), encoding));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line + "\r\n");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return builder.toString();
}
```